# How to Update Collections in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to update collection of User who signed up yesterday into our system. My objective is to find the users who registered yesterday and set `isActive` to `true`. I am able to get list of users who registered on specific date but not sure on how to update them

This is the query I am using to select list of user. I am using this from inside *Azure > Azure Cosmos DB > Query Explorer*

```
SELECT * FROM UserAccounts u WHERE u.isActive = false AND u.signupDate
>= "2017-12-18" AND u.signupDate <= "2017-12-19"
```

I am getting list of 26 users who signed up yesterday using this query.
I was referring to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query) of MSFT but couldn't find how.

If this cannot be done using Query Explorer, then please mention how can I do this change internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query Explorer in the Azure Portal is only to run Queries, not perform Insert/Update operations.

You can use the [Data Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/documentdb-data-explorer-preview-now-available-in-the-azure-portal/) to run queries and access and edit the filtered results the way you want.

[image: Data Explorer access menu]

In the **Documents** section, you can apply a **Filter** as a Query (your WHERE clause), then click on the results and edit and **Update** them.

[image: Filtering in Data Explorer]

Just remember to only apply the WHERE clause in the Filter section, in your case, `WHERE c.isActive = false AND c.signupDate >= "2017-12-18" AND c.signupDate <= "2017-12-19"` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, I see there's an Update button in Data Explorer (on top) to update your changes to the current document. Thanks!